# How to give import action to a button in odoo?

Tags: odoo, python-import, odoo-10, import-from-excel

I want to give the import/export action to a custom button in odoo 10, in csv file or excel file.
How to do it?

Thank You

Comment: Why does you arent want to use the default export csv of Odoo ?

Comment: I can use the default import button to import/export files.But I want to place the import button in a wizard. @jo541

Answer (score 2):

The method calling when you click on the button export is `export_data`

You can see the code in the file models.py in folder /odoo/odoo/models.py

```
@api.multi
def export_data(self, fields_to_export, raw_data=False):
    """ Export fields for selected objects

        :param fields_to_export: list of fields
        :param raw_data: True to return value in native Python type
        :rtype: dictionary with a *datas* matrix

        This method is used when exporting data via client menu
    """
    fields_to_export = map(fix_import_export_id_paths, fields_to_export)
    if raw_data:
        self = self.with_context(export_raw_data=True)
    return {'datas': self._export_rows(fields_to_export)}
```

I don't try but I think you must do like this

```
@api.multi
def execute(self):
    model = "name_of_your_model_want_export"
    export_datas = self.env[model].export_data(['field1', 'field2'])
    # code to write to a file CSV of EXCEL
```

For the import. You must do use the create method of the model.

```
@api.multi
def execute(self):
    # This function return list of dict like this 
    # [{'field1': 'Value1','field2': 'value2}, {'field1': 'Value1','field2': 'value2}]
    datas = data_from_your_csv(self.file) 
    model = "name_of_your_model_want_import"
    for data in datas:
        record = self.env[model].create(data)
```

Comment: What about import? @jo541

Comment: Thanks. But I can't understand this line :                                                                      
   datas = data_from_your_csv(self.file)   @jo541

Comment: This line consists to get all the information from your CSV. You need to read CSV, format data like this  [{'field1': 'Value1','field2': 'value2}, {'field1': 'Value1','field2': 'value2}]